# Not Hitting Native Breakpoints in VS2015

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, debugging, c++-cli

My Setup:
Visual Studio 2015
C# Application with a C++/CLI dll, which references an unmanaged C++ static library. Application is compiled for x64 only.

When debugging, I can set breakpoints all I want in the unmanaged C++ static library code, but they are ignored.

Yes, the Modules window shows that symbols are loaded.

Yes, in the C# application "Use Native Debugging" is checked.

Yes, in the C++ library "Debugger Type" is set to "Mixed"

Yes, the breakpoints are solid red and do not indicate any issues.

Furthermore, if an exception is thrown in the C++ library (such as an access violation) the debugger breaks in as expected and allows me to view local context as expected. But debug breakpoints in the same context are just blatantly ignored. I can also step from managed code, into the library code properly. I just don't understand why breakpoints aren't working...

Any help which would allow my breakpoints to properly break in would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tools > Options > Debugging > General > tick the "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" option.

Comment: If you manually add a [`__debugbreak`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f408b4et.aspx), will that break?

Comment: Hans Passant, you were correct. That fixed it! Strange how using managed compatibility mode allows unmanaged breakpoints to hit. Regardless that makes debugging **so** much easier. Thanks!